# cakephp cron job - Missing database table

Tags: shell, cakephp, cron

I have a report.php file created in `app/vendors/shells` folder with the following content

```
class ReportShell extends Shell {
    var $uses = array('User');

    function main() {
        $userData = $this->User->find('first');
    }
}
```

when I want to run it from app folder `../cake/console/cake report` I get the following error

`Error: Missing database table 'users' for model 'User'`

`users` table does exist in db, `User` model as well. And the project works fine, I mean there are no issues with models, controllers, views. My cake version is 1.3

Thanks

Comment: Try checking what db config it's using by running `debug(ConnectionManager::enumConnectionObjects());` .  Or maybe it's probably not finding the User model and creating one on the fly -- try creating a custom function in the User model and calling it from the shell to see if it's seen.

Comment: Thanks @Costa for your comment, debug results($result) contains `$result['config']` array according to my `$default` configuration, so it's ok, I have also created another model with `$useTable = false`, and a custom function in it, that worked fine, so it can use model, but as before, fails to find `users` table

Comment: Thanks @Costa for your help, I figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the problem was that in db config instead of `'host' => 'localhost'` it was necessary to write `'host' => '127.0.0.1'`, see also this answer

[How do I get CakePHP bake to find mysql.sock and recognize MySQL while using MAMP on Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366550/how-do-i-get-cakephp-bake-to-find-mysql-sock-and-recognize-mysql-while-using-mam/366556#366556)