# CakePHP Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created

Tags: php, mysql, macos, cakephp, mamp

There have been several other posts about this, but none of the answers seemed to work for me.

When I navigate to the CakePHP page on my local machine, there is one error:

> Cake is NOT able to connect to the database. Database connection
>   "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.

When I run [this helpful code](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) in my home.ctp, I get the following response:

> Error!: SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'test'

However, my `Users/Ben/Sites/myapp/app/Config/database.php` looks like this (I set MAMP to look for the document root in Users/Ben/Sites):

```
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'Ben',
        'password' => 'mypass',
        'database' => 'CV',
    );
}
```

I have created a mysql user called `Ben` with password `mypass` and created a database called `CV` under that. Moreover, I can't find mention of a `test` database anywhere. Help?

Comment: I was getting the same error message and in my case changing permissions for whole Model directory helped a lot.

Answer (score 51):

Try adding the socket:

```
'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

Comment: Just so you don't wonder where to add this, put is on the last line of your database configuration (for example default) ... I am for example using XAMPP and the file is here: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: Thats correct, I supposed to many things from reading the question. :)

Comment: Adding this allowed my Cron job to execute on a Mac running XAMPP.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI this worked on my XAMPP installation too except I had to put /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: Not everyone is using xampp (especially for OS X people out there). Find out where your mysql.sock is. i'm using OS X 10.9+ and it was:
         
       'unix_socket' => '/tmp/mysql.sock',

Apple has been changing the location of mysql.sock.

include that line as the last part of the $default array

Comment: Had to do this for XAMPP on Arch Linux as well.

Answer (score 22):

An alternative to `unix_socket` (especially for OS X people) is to replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`

Would be as Follows :

```
public $default = array(
                'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
                'persistent' => false,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'login' => 'user',
                'password' => 'password',
                'database' => 'database-name',
                'prefix' => '',
                'encoding' => 'utf8',
        );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is irrelevant if your database is hosted externally. :-(

Comment: @UncaAlby, Obviously. What can we do! :-D The question concerned a local environment...

Answer (score 13):

Edit `php.ini` and add:

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Then restart your web server

Comment: Thanks.. this is work for me. i am using cakePHP 2.5.4, IIS 8,PHP 5.4.24

Comment: This has worked for me too with an old Cake 2.6.1 project with PHP 5.5.9.

Answer (score 10):

On Mac, using MAMP as a development platform, for cake the correct solution is using Domingo Casarrubio solution.

Add the `unix_socket` parameter to your database configurations.

```
'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: @VictorAugusto using 'localhost' as host in database.php will cause CakePHP to try to connect to a local socket file. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366550/how-do-i-get-cakephp-bake-to-find-mysql-sock-and-recognize-mysql-while-using-mam)

Answer (score 6):

This error can also be caused if your connecting database user doesn't have the proper privileges. I believe you only need a minimum of INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, and DELETE.

Always check username/password *and* the user privileges first since CakePHP will most likely give a vague database connection error for either.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and found out eventually that it was caused by CakePhp not accepting that I used a user with a password, even if that user was created in PHPMyAdmin. I had to use the user 'root' with no password.

I found this out after making the following change to the file */lib/Cake/Error/exceptions.php*.

The original line:

```
protected $_messageTemplate = 'Database connection "%s" is missing, or could not be created.';
```

is changed into this instead (note the change from single to double quotes):

```
protected $_messageTemplate = "Database connection \"%s\" is missing, or could not be created:\n    %s";
```

This will give you the reason for the problem so that you may change the cause properly.

Comment: Amazing tip. This will tell you the exact reason for this error. This should have more votes.

Comment: @SimonEast I agree. Why don't they include that in the original message out of the box? Any time you get an error, you need to have as much relevant information as possible so you can properly fix it. If you're afraid of giving away too much to a hacker, then write it out to a log-file somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed that you've had asked this an year ago, and most probably would've solved this by now. However, for those facing the same issues when attempting to install CakePHP on XAMPP, all you have to do is change the 'login' to 'root', i.e. the default login of XAMPP, and leave the 'password' as '', i.e. blank. The complete code in your database.php file should look like this:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'ckblog',//replace with your own database name
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks! it helped!
I am using Uniform Server.

Comment: Going in circles trying to get my Bitnami to talk to my windows MySql database. Thanks! I also used my vendors folder for the lib source for cakephp.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem since upgrading to OSX Yosemite and inserting following line did the trick for me:

```html
 'unix_socket' => '/tmp/mysql.sock'
```

Comment: Which is roughly what the top two answers say.

Answer (score 2):

It can be that mysql PDO support is missing.

as root (or using sudo):

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to help **Ubuntu** users out:
I had the same error in my ubuntu 13.10 machine with the newest xampp downlaoded directly from apachefriends. Tried most of the stuff in every post I could find about this error, but not the mac-specific stuff.
In the end, the fix happened to be the same as the elected answer here:

Find the socket that mysqld creates for programs to connect to:

```
user@host /opt$ find . -name mysql.sock
/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

add it to your cakePHP database configuration file (cakePHP)/app/Config/database.php

```
'unix_socket' => '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

To me, this finally resulted in my cake commands being able to be executed without the "*Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.*".

Answer (score 1):

Because, cake bake use unix socket for connecting to database
so that you need add unix_socket for connection string.
You have to confirm location that store mysql.sock in WAS
Example: in my case i'm using xampp on MACOS 10.11
(edit file Config/database.php)

```
public $default = array(
  ‘datasource’ => ‘Database/Mysql’,
  ‘persistent’ => false,
  ‘host’ => ‘localhost’,
  ‘login’ => ‘root’,
  ‘password’ => ‘root’,
  ‘database’ => ‘cakephp’,
  ‘encoding’ => ‘utf8’,
  ‘unix_socket’ => ‘/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock’
);
```

Finally, It's work for me!

Answer (score 0):

What did it for me in the end was that I had created a table in my database, but there was no data in it.

In order for CakePHP to recognize the MySql connection, there has to be a table with data in it.

Comment: That is simply not true. -1.

Comment: This fixed my issue. CakePHP had the right credentials but I the database did not exist. If you look through Cake's source you'll see there isn't a check in case the Database doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create the table in your php file... Open up phpMyAdmin and check to ensure that they database CV exists.

Answer (score 0):

It's your model. Open that up and there must be the following line

```
public $useDbConfig = 'local';
```

This overwrites global config & set it back to local

Comment: Be careful. Unless you know exactly what this line is doing, this may cause issues for you later.

Answer (score 0):

I tried splicing the code from Example 2 of http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php into /app/View/Pages/home.ctp.  I had to fix the arguments the PDO constructor and change the name of the table in the query.  The example 2 code returned the error "Error!: could not find driver".  Based on King Jk's answer I was attempting to modify the php.ini when I started to wonder where a php_pdo_mysql.so might live.  http://php.net/pdo_mysql showed how it was compiled as part of PHP via the --with-pdo-mysql option to configure.  Recompiling fixed my problem.   Note I'm working on a Ubuntu 12.10 system with PHP 5.5.9 and Apache Webserver 2.4.6

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because the database didn't exist. I expected running `./app/Console/cake schema create` would create it but it did not. Creating it with `create database <database name>` in mysql did the trick (although I had already assigned privileges).

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this the whole weekend and finally solved it. Turns out that the php.ini is pointing to a non-existing "extensions dir". Create a phpinfo() file and look at the value of this field:
[image: extensions_dir]

I noticed that in the mamp php installed folder there is a no-debug-non-zts-20131226 folder, which is different from the value shown in the phpinfo(). What I did was to clone this folder and changed the name to the value of the phpinfo(). Probably you could modify the php.ini file but I didn't want to.

I don't know if you solved your problem, but I'm posting this because my problem was different and google took me here, so I hope to help future googlers having a similiar issue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Godaddy (or any other shared hosting for that matter), they may be limiting outgoing connections to ports 80 and 443 only.

Answer (score 0):

System configuration:

- Fedora 32
- php-fpm 7.4.13
- mariadb 10.4.17
- CAKE 2.10.17

Error message from CAKE:

> Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.

Enhanced error message using answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24722976/5025060

> Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created: Selected driver is not enabled

My problem was no "connector" between PHP and SQL was installed.  The solution was:

`dnf install php-mysqlnd`

This allowed PHP to connect to the database as specified in CAKE's database.php configuration file.