# Database configuration Issue CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

My database.php :

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/MySql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'cake_database',
        'schema' => '',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
    );

    public $test = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/MySql',
        'persistent' => true,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'cake_database',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
}
```

Shows this notice : CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.

Please help...........

Comment: Well is your MySQL server started?

Comment: Also the default login for MySQL is root. You don't have any user specified

Comment: I use wamp server . It is running .

Comment: Well try specifying the user and the password if you set one when you installed wamp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280245/cakephp-database-connection-mysql-is-missing-or-could-not-be-created). There a few SO posts about this topic.

Comment: Finally I solved by changing following line in code .                                 'host' => '127.0.0.1',
'login' => 'root',                                                                                      Thanks for your respons..........Catalin Munteanu & AgRizzo

Comment: I'm pretty sure it wasn't cause by replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`. The problem was the user not being specified. I'm glad you solved it.

Comment: A note for u in the upcoming setup. By default, MySQL username will always be root..It cannot be empty.

Answer (score 0):

public $default = array( 'datasource' => 'Database/MySql', 'persistent' => false, 'host' => 'localhost', 'login' => 'root', 'password' => '', 'database' => 'cake_database', 'schema' => '', 'prefix' => '', 'encoding' => 'utf8' );

Mysql default login is root and password empty,

If you have change it, you must enter the user and the password to access database..

It's just because cakephp failed connect to mysql..